# Simple jQuery "push" menu - offset main container and menu but transition timings not correct

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a simple off-canvas "push" menu. When the menu trigger is clicked, the menu slides in from the right of the viewport and pushes the main content divs offset by the width of the menu.

The jQuery works (in that is pushes the menu onto the page, and pushes the content off the page) but the animations do not work as expected. There is some "catchup" where the menu moves slower than the main content areas.

I set a `transition-delay` to fix this issue but it doesn't seem to have had the effect I thought it would.

How do I managed to get the content divs to move offscreen so that it looks like they are pushed by the menu?

Here is an example of my issue: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GrKJor

Here is my code:

```
$('.nav-trigger').click(function(){
  $('nav').addClass('nav--open');
  $('header').addClass('content--pushed');
  $('main').addClass('content--pushed');
  $('footer').addClass('content--pushed');
});
```

And here is the CSS for the transition:

```
nav {
  ...
  right: -300px;
  transition: right 0.2s ease-in;
}

.nav--open {
  right: 0px;
}

.content--pushed {
  position: relative;
  right: 300px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is you're attempting to animate a property - specifically, right position - in a way that will only work in your markup structure if the element being animated has a `position:fixed`.

You can see the desired behavior in this forked CodePen:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ygBNXG

(I also added a 'nav-close' button so you can see the inverse & test repeatedly)

By applying a fixed position to the header, main & footer, the transition effect can indeed be animated:

```
header, main, footer {
  position: fixed;
  /* other CSS */
}
```

To account for the fixed position, I've then offset the top position of main & footer based on your defined heights:

```
main {
  top:100px
}
footer {
  top:200px
}
```

Finally, and this is only preference, I made the left position of header, main & footer be what changes (from 0 to -300px) as that seems to more accurately reflect what's happening, which is those elements are being moved off the left edge of the viewport by 300px.

**Update**

If you don't want to use `position:fixed` on the elements, you need to modify your markup structure to wrap the header, main & footer elements and place the nav element *outside* of said wrapper. This is working sans fixed position and heights/offsets here:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qREvEB

The revised markup is essentially:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <header>...</header>
  <main>...</main>
  <footer>...</footer>
</div>
<nav>...</nav>
```

In this scenario, the positions of the header, main & footer can be reset to relative and the content is all scrollable as needed.

Comment: With `position:fixed` on the content elements, does this mean the page loses it's scrollable ability?

Comment: No, not at all; your page & content will still be scrollable. You can confirm this by simply increasing the height (and corresponding top offsets) of your header, main & footer elements. You may be mixing up `fixed` and `absolute` positioning.

Comment: I'm afraid I've tried on the codepen and find that adding the `position:fixed` the elements become unscrollable and are indeed, fixed in place on the page.

Comment: If using `position:fixed` doesn't net your desired result, you'll need to consider a change to your markup and wrap the header, main & footer elements inside another element with the nav element *outside*. See my updated answer for a second example CodePen.